# Get all OffMeshLink objects in Unity

Tags: unity, navmesh

What I'm trying to do is to make an edit-mode script that gets all off-mesh links and makes some of them bi-directional(depends whether a jump is possible).

My (obvious) attempt was:

```
FindObjectsOfType<OffMeshLink>();
```

However, it returns only the links I have created manually.

My question is the following: how to access the off-mesh links generated by unity in the baked NavMesh?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Baked stuff are generally in a separate file. If you do manage to find a way though, please let us know here :)

Comment: @JohnHamilton I've got an answer at Unity forum that it's not possible to modify data of the baked NavMesh. Still hoping to find a way to read it, though.